# "404 error - File or Directory not found" error on mobile browser in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api2, android-chrome

I am trying token-based authentication in ASP.NET MVC 5. Everything is working on a PC browser (Login page, Register page, Data page).

Here is login script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSignIn').click(function () {
        var loginData = {
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: $('#txtSignInEmail').val(),
            password: $('#txtSignInPassword').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Token',
            data: loginData
        }).done(function (data) {

            $('#user').text(data.userName)
            $('#UserName').text(JSON.stringify(data.userName));

            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.access_token);
            localStorage.setItem('qubaUserName', JSON.stringify(data.userName));
        }).fail(function (showError) {
            $('#signInError').text(JSON.stringify(showError));
        });
    });
})
</script>
```

When I try to login on my PC, it successfully logged in.

But on my mobile, it shows an error as shown in the screenshot.

**Update**

It is only on mobile Chrome browser. I checked with Mozilla, and it shows exactly what I expect

[image: Mobile Chrome Error]

**UPDATE**

> If I make the `url:'Token'`, It works on local machine and Mozilla browser in Android, but not in any other PC(both chrome and Mozilla) and Android(chrome browser)

**when URL: 'Token'**

it makes a request from local pc to this link `http://localhost/ProjectName/Token`

But it makes a request from other pc browser and Android Chrome browser like `http://localhost/Token`

> If I change the `URL:'ProjectName/Token'` not working in local pc(Where I deployed on IIS), But, it working in all Android browser(chrome and Mozilla) and other pc

**when URL: 'ProjectName/Token'**

> it makes a request from local pc to this link `http://localhost/ProjectName/ProjectName/Token`

But it makes a request from other pc browser and Android Chrome browser like `http://localhost/ProjectName/Token`

So how can I make common URL for all client(both local pc and remote client)

Comment: Nobody have any Idea

Comment: You need to trace your code where issue occurred. also how you are testing your code ? this screen shot is not from web browser please clarify

Comment: @MohammadAlghanem this screenshot from my mobile chrome browser

Comment: Add dataType: 'text' to your ajax request , and in your back end receive the data as String and let me know the result

Comment: Have you tried using absolute url, with `/` at the beginning? Like `/Token` or `/{ControllerName}/Token`

Comment: Could you please add you route configuration in web api?

Comment: @Alexander could you please check my updates

Comment: @Liamneesan And have you tried `/ProjectName/Token/` with `/` at the beginning? It should request to `localhost/ProjectName/Token` from any device I believe

Comment: @Alexander wait

Comment: @Alexander you are correct. write your answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change url to an absolute one with the `/` at the beginning.

```
"/ProjectName/Token"
```

It will definitely point to `http://localhost/ProjectName/Token` no matter from what url your js script is called.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Token',

change this url token to /token or full qualified path

Comment: I tried with `/token`, It cannot access that url even from computer browser